# Related rate problem with circle

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've worked with related rate before, but this question stumped me.

The radius of a circle is increasing at a nonzero rate, and at a certain instant the rate of increase in the area of the circle is numerically equal to the rate of increase in its circumference.

What is the radius of the circle at this instant?

Comment: Is this question from an online school?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $A = \pi r^2$, $\dfrac {dA}{dt} = 2\pi r \dfrac {dr}{dt}$.

From $C = 2\pi r$, $\dfrac {dC}{dt} = 2\pi \dfrac {dr}{dt}$.

Equating the two to get r = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Write down what you are given: $\frac {dr}{dt}=k$ and $\frac {dA}{dt}=k.$  Express $A$ as a function of $r$, take the indicated derivative, and set the two $k$'s equal.  What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

At any instant, rate of increase or marginal growth is double the radial marginal growth rate and they can *never be equal*.

$$A = \pi r^2 , \dfrac {dA}{dr} = 2\pi r, \quad C = 2\pi r , \dfrac {dC}{dr} = 2\pi, $$
When we equate *unit non-dimensional* or percentage growths.

$$ \frac{dA}{A}= \frac{dC}{C},  \quad 2 =1 \, ! $$

Similarly volumetric growth rate of a sphere can never match its radial growth rate.